# read txt file into 2d array force exit

Tags: java, android, file, text

firstly i am sorry for my broken english. I wanna read txt file and into 2d array. this code is succesfully running on java. but android emulator gives warning message: "Sorry! the application has stopped unexpectedly. please try again"

how can I fix that? thanks

here is my code:

```
package com.example.hocam;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Konular extends ActionBarActivity {

  private ListView konuListe;
  private List<KonuBilgileri> konuBilgileri;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_konular);
    Bundle dersadi = getIntent().getExtras();
    String dersinadi= dersadi.getString("Ders");

   switch(dersinadi)  {
   case "Turkce": 
       KonuGetir turkce=new KonuGetir("turkce.txt");

       String[][] turkcekonular=turkce.getKonular();

      System.out.println(turkcekonular[0][0]);  // it is the problem and give error
       konuListe = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.konu_listesi);
        konuBilgileri = new ArrayList<KonuBilgileri>();
       konuBilgileri.add(new KonuBilgileri(turkcekonular[0][0],R.drawable.turkce, turkcekonular[0][1]));  // array is problem

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(Konular.this, R.layout.custom_list_item, konuBilgileri);
       konuListe.setAdapter(adapter);

       break;

   }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.konular, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}

 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.util.Scanner;

public class KonuGetir {
final int maxLines = 10100;
String[][] resultArray = new String[maxLines][];

public KonuGetir(String Ders){
      File file = new File(Ders);
        Scanner scanner;
        try {
            scanner = new Scanner(file,"utf-8");
             int linesCounter = 0;
                while (scanner.hasNextLine() && linesCounter < maxLines) {
                    resultArray[linesCounter] = scanner.nextLine().split("@");
                    linesCounter++;
                }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
public String[][] getKonular()  {
    return resultArray;
}
}
```

logfile:

```
> 09-04 16:18:22.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1164): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-04 16:18:22.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1164): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hocam/com.example.hocam.Konular}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-04 16:18:22.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
09-04 16:18:22.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-04 16:18:22.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-04 16:18:22.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-04 16:18:22.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-04 16:18:22.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-04 16:18:22.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-04 16:18:22.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-04 16:18:22.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-04 16:18:22.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-04 16:18:22.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-04 16:18:22.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-04 16:18:22.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1164): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-04 16:18:22.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at com.example.hocam.Konular.onCreate(Konular.java:66)
09-04 16:18:22.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-04 16:18:22.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-04 16:18:22.262: E/AndroidRuntime(1164):     ... 11 more
09-04 16:42:10.422: E/AndroidRuntime(1178): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-04 16:42:10.422: E/AndroidRuntime(1178): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hocam/com.example.hocam.Konular}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-04 16:42:10.422: E/AndroidRuntime(1178):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
09-04 16:42:10.422: E/AndroidRuntime(1178):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-04 16:42:10.422: E/AndroidRuntime(1178):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-04 16:42:10.422: E/AndroidRuntime(1178):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-04 16:42:10.422: E/AndroidRuntime(1178):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-04 16:42:10.422: E/AndroidRuntime(1178):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-04 16:42:10.422: E/AndroidRuntime(1178):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-04 16:42:10.422: E/AndroidRuntime(1178):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-04 16:42:10.422: E/AndroidRuntime(1178):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-04 16:42:10.422: E/AndroidRuntime(1178):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-04 16:42:10.422: E/AndroidRuntime(1178):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-04 16:42:10.422: E/AndroidRuntime(1178):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-04 16:42:10.422: E/AndroidRuntime(1178): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-04 16:42:10.422: E/AndroidRuntime(1178):     at com.example.hocam.Konular.onCreate(Konular.java:66)
09-04 16:42:10.422: E/AndroidRuntime(1178):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-04 16:42:10.422: E/AndroidRuntime(1178):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-04 16:42:10.422: E/AndroidRuntime(1178):     ... 11 more
09-04 16:43:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1207): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-04 16:43:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1207): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hocam/com.example.hocam.Konular}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-04 16:43:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1207):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
09-04 16:43:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1207):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-04 16:43:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1207):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-04 16:43:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1207):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-04 16:43:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1207):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-04 16:43:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1207):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-04 16:43:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1207):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-04 16:43:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1207):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-04 16:43:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1207):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-04 16:43:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1207):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-04 16:43:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1207):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-04 16:43:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1207):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-04 16:43:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1207): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-04 16:43:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1207):     at com.example.hocam.Konular.onCreate(Konular.java:66)
09-04 16:43:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1207):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-04 16:43:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1207):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-04 16:43:28.802: E/AndroidRuntime(1207):     ... 11 more
```

android manifest file:

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
>
> <uses-sdk
>     android:minSdkVersion="8"
>     android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
>
> <application
>     android:allowBackup="true"
>     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
>     android:label="@string/app_name"
>     android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
>     <activity
>         android:name=".MainActivity"
>         android:label="@string/app_name" >
>         <intent-filter>
>             <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>
>             <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>         </intent-filter>
>     </activity>
>     <activity
>         android:name=".YGS"
>         android:label="@string/title_activity_ygs" >
>     </activity>
>     <activity
>         android:name=".Konular"
>         android:label="@string/title_activity_konular" >
>     </activity>
>     <activity
>         android:name=".Video"
>         android:screenOrientation="landscape"
>         android:label="@string/title_activity_video" >
>
>     </activity>
> </application>
> ```

Comment: So what does the stack trace in the log look like? (I personally wouldn't call a dialog indicating that your app has crashed a "warning" but never mind...)

Comment: Post your Manifest.xml file too.

Comment: I posted manifest.xml file @DavidCAdams

Answer (score 0):

You are using the following code:

```
  String[][] turkcekonular=turkce.getKonular();

  System.out.println(turkcekonular[0][0]);
```

But get `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

The reason for this because `getKonular()` returns an array initalised to size `10100`, however `scanner` does not contain any lines so `scanner.hasNextLine()` is false.

This means that `turkcekonular[0]` is null, as it was never set. 
Which means that `turkcekonular[0][0]` is trying to access a null object, so throws a `NullPointerException`

You should check if the object is null before trying to access it..

```
 if(turkcekonular[0] != null)
      System.out.println(turkcekonular[0][0]);
```

and else where that this issue occurs.

(and you should figure out why your file is not read. Is it named correctly and exists in the specified path?)

Comment: firstly thank you for your answer. i changed my code  if(turkcekonular[0] != null)
      System.out.println(turkcekonular[0][0]);  there are no any force exit. i think the problem is KonuGetir class. by the way I fixed named correctly. what can I fixed my reading txt file method? thanks again @Doomsknight

Comment: by the way my text file into project file (Hocam) directory

Comment: @KaaNSARIKAYA Use `if(!file.exists()) System.out.println("FILE DOES NOT EXIST");`  To see if the file even exists/ can be found. Apart from that your code looks ok. You could try reading lines using a buffered reader instead. http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/io/bufferedreader/read-file-with-bufferedreader-example/  If that doesnt work, You should ask another question regarding why your reader isnt working. As this answer does fix the crash you asked about. And accept this answer :) thanks